# Could not find implicit format for parameter

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have the following case class:

```
case class Customer(name: String)
```

That is encoded like this:

```
class ServiceJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val customerProtocol = jsonFormat1(Customer)
}
```

The problem is that for this code:

```
val route =
  path("customer") {
    post {
      entity(as[Customer]) {
        customer => complete {
          customers.add(customer)
          s"got customer with name ${customer.name}"
        }
      }
    }
```

I am getting this:

```
 could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[Customer]
[error]           entity(as[Customer]) {
```

What is the issue?

Comment: If you're using `spray-json`, please mention it in your question. Also, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574176/akka-http-could-not-find-implicit-value-for-parameter-unmarshalling

Answer (score 4):

You have to extend SprayJsonSupport. This compiles:

```
import spray.json._
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport

case class Customer(name: String)

object ServiceJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val customerProtocol = jsonFormat1(Customer)
}

class RateRoutes extends SprayJsonSupport {

  import ServiceJsonProtocol._

  val route =
    path("customer") {
      post {
        entity(as[Customer]) {
          customer => complete {
            customers.add(customer)
            s"got customer with name ${customer.name}"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I suppose your using akka http. With Spray this error should not happen.